# Is there a way to automatically create address points in the middle of an already created parcel?

Tags: arcgis-pro, address

I have 250 created parcels.  Within the attribute table are addresses of the parcels.  I was hoping to create a new layer with address points.  Is there a tool/way to automatically create a feature class that would put an address point in the middle of these parcels?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Feature to Point tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm).  You will want to use the 'Inside' option to make sure that each point is actually within each polygon (some polygons have such weird shapes that their centroid point is not actually within the polygon).